# React parse localStorage problems (Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'u', "function st"... is not valid JSON)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, parsing

I'm learning the React ropes and am attempting make my app check for local storage before making a fetch request. Pretty sure my code is solid but I keep getting this error in my console.log

```
VM79:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'u', "function st"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at getPopular (Popular.jsx:19:1)
    at Popular.jsx:13:1
```

I figure it's something to do with my if/else. Before implementing it everything is fine, but with it in (viewing from my localhost) it won't fetch and display images from the api I am using. Can anyone help?

```
Popular.jsx


const Popular = () => {
  const [popular, setPopular] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPopular();
  }, []);

  const getPopular = async () => {

    const check = localStorage.getItem("popular");

    if (check) {
      setPopular(JSON.parse(check));


    } else {
      const url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/random";
      const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
      const res = await fetch(`${url}?apiKey=${apiKey}&number=9`);
      const data = await res.json();
      localStorage.setItem("popular", JSON.stringify(data.recipes));
      setPopular(data.recipes);
      console.log("Restore popular");
    }
  };
```

Comment: what is the value of `check` when logged ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `check` is not a json. Check if it's a json before assigning to the state

```
const isJson = (str) => {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


 const getPopular = async () => {

    const check = localStorage.getItem("popular");

    if (check && isJson(check)) {
      setPopular(JSON.parse(check));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks Sachila, sending good internet karma your way :)